# Handling disabled button in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have an update button in the site which seems to be disabled. But when I clicked it manually it is clickable and an alert came. Actually It should not be clickable which is a failure of functionality test. How to automate that using selenium webdriver

Comment: add complete details like some of your `code ` (the way you are trying) and some `html` snippet (off-course your element )

Comment: public static boolean isClickable(WebElement webe)      
{
try
{
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourWebDriver, 5);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webe));
   return false;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  return true;
}Called this method in class.


boolean bst = className.isClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("update"));

Comment: just increase your wait  limit 5 to `120 seconds ` and interchange the `return` values  I think it should `return false` in `catch` block and `return true` in `try` block

Comment: Thank you for your responseActually what I want is if the buttonis  clickable test should show failure message, When I checked manually even the update button is shown disabled , we can click on that.That is why I have changed the return value in try and catch block.

Comment: Increased time limit helping you ?

Comment: No.. Its not working

Comment: It works when I did like this                                                                          boolean bst = Clickable.isClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("update"));
   if (bst==true)
     {
     Assert.assertFalse(false);
     }
   else
   {
     Assert.assertFalse(true);

Comment: Thanks  Narendra for your timely response